# How to enter a PHP variable in single brackets in this case

Tags: php, variables

Please, help resolve the issue. There is a code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://woo.elementcreator.com?wc-api=serial-numbers-api",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('request' => 'check','email' => 'vic@gmail.com', 'serial_key' => '11111','product_id' => '212'),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$teste = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($teste);
```

Instead of the default values (email, serial_key), I need to enter the variables in this line:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('request' => 'check','email' => 'vic@gmail.com', 'serial_key' => 
'11111','product_id' => '212'),
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean about entering the variables in the array, do you mean something like `'product_id' => $productID`?

Comment: Yes, this is work for me, thanks